# Movie with the last of an alien race at the end?

Tags: story-identification, movie

Just watched Total Recall for the first time in 20+ years, and I could have sworn that I remembered that the last of the long dead aliens appeared - but was completely wrong. I can't figure out which movie I conflated the ending with. I even have them on a dusty/rocky slope in my head.

My wife thinks I just imagined it, but it feels like a deeper implanted memory than that (no total recall jokes intended!)

Ok. So date wise, I can't say - late 70s thru 2000 I'd have to guess.

What did the alien look like? This is the hardest part. I could have sworn it was a realistic lizard-like one, kind of like G-kar from Babylon 5, but not as humanoid. I don't recall if it was clothed or not. I'm wondering if maybe I'm conflating it with the Supergirl Mars stories, but I don't think so.

The thing that's driving me nuts is that I was certain it was on the side of a rocky mountain they'd been expelled from, just like in Total Recall.

Could it have been in written form eg Ray Bradbury or even Patrick Moore's Mars book? Possibly, but I don't think so.

Just watched The Martian and Enemy Mine, close but no cigar. Similar tropes though, and I can see why Mission to Mars was suggested too.

Being British, is it possible it's a Doctor Who story? I don't think so, but you never know.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SciFi Exchange! Could you please take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/39144) and [edit] in any extra details you can remember? For example: when did you watch this movie? Was it in cinema or DVD or online?

Comment: Describe your alien, how it looks like, what he was doing?

Comment: This could also be something from the Ray Bradbury Theater. He wrote a lot of Mars-related stories. A number of them were made into episodes of his show. It is on Comet TV now.

Comment: I've described it and add a not very helpful time-range.

Comment: I checked out Ray Bradbury theater -- brought back memories. I definitely saw the Martian, but then ending isn't exactly what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 5):

Could it be [Mission to Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_to_Mars)?

In the end

> the survivors of the human mission can enter the martian building and meet the last Martian (an hologram of course) that explains them the end of life on Mars and the subsequent the origin of life on Earth.

Comment: Thanks - I checked it out, and it wasn't what I was thinking of. I'm not even sure if I saw that one.

Answer (score 0):

Your description could possibly stretch to cover the skeksis in the original *Dark Crystal* (1982) -- this was a vaguely lizard-like creature, with a long snout and many sharp teeth, dark in color.  It was an entire race, but the singular and plural are the same (like moose), and they were seen in a number of different settings.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Skeksis_on_Display_(red_blur).jpg

Comment: Definitely wasn't Dark Crystal. Was more sci-fi.